# Angular 2 app does not run on IIS server

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have an Angular 2 app that is running properly when I do ng-serve, however when I migrate it to IIS, its not working properly, its stuck on the loading....screen.

I am pointing my folder to root folder.

Do I need to do a different setup?  Or install any extra things?

Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: did you build the app or just copy the project?

Comment: no i just pointed IIS to the project folder.  Do you need to build the project?  And if so how?  Its my first Angular 2 project that I am migrating to  IIS

Comment: `ng build --base-href <webURL>`will do the job where `<webURL>` is your website url that points to the web app

Comment: so i went inside my angular proejct directory and i tried that ng build --base-href myangularapi.mywebsite.com however I still cannot see anything, still loading screen

Comment: `ng build --base-href http://myangularapi.mywebsite.com` or `ng build --base-href https://myangularapi.mywebsite.com` depending on whether or not you have ssl

Comment: i tried that but it stil did not work.  I also tried to restart my IIS Server but still stuck on the loading..... page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142625/discussion-between-mast3rd3mon-and-johann).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found my error.  Basically what I did was ng build on my local folder, move the dist folder to my server, and then in the index, I had to change `<base href="/">` to `<base href="">`, and that worked perfectly.